# Problem powering up the signal in interceptor

Tags: fallout-4

[image]

I did this whole set up but it still says I need to power up the signal interceptor but I don't know who can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure they are connected by wiring all parts together, that you've talked to the correct people (depends on faction), and that you've completed all other objectives of this quest.

Comment: I did all that everything is connected and everything and everything is powered and on and I don't have anymore objectives but it still says power up the signal interceptor

Comment: And also I did it at the Boston airport does that matter?

Comment: @NickBenotti What did you do to fix the problem? We have lots of people ask about this quest. Your solution may help others.